# Casting an inherited object

Tags: c#

I guess that this is a simple question for most of you but none of the answers I have seen on the web are what I need. So, I have a base class and another one that inherits it:

```
public class MyBase
{
    public DateAdded { get; set; }
}

public class MySecond : MyBase
{
    public MySecond(MyBase prototype) 
    {
        this = (MySecond)prototype; // this is read-only and does not work
    }

    public DateDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

How to instanciate a MyBase, provide it as a prototype to another instance of MySecond and make sure the latter gets all the values of the prototype without explicitly transferring the values one-by-one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot do the copying automatically, but you can do it in a shared spot - i.e. in the constructor of the `MyBase` class. This way all derived classes would be able to use the same shared code if you pass the `prototype` as the parameter of your base constructor, like this:

```
public class MyBase {
    public DateAdded { get; set; }
    public MyBase() {
    }
    public MyBase(MyBase other) {
        // Do the copying here
    }
}

public class MySecond : MyBase {
    public MySecond(MyBase prototype) : base(prototype) {
    }

    public DateDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT** (in response to a comment)

If you do not have access to the source of `MyBase`, you can make a static helper method that does the copying for you, like this:

```
internal static class MyBaseHelper {
    public static void CopyFromBase(this MyBase target, MyBase source) {
        target.DateAdded = source.DateAdded;
    }
}
```

Now you can use it in your derived classes like this:

```
public class MySecond : MyBase {
    public MySecond(MyBase prototype) {
        this.CopyFromBase(prototype);
    }

    public DateDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: And what if I cannot change the file of the MyBase class?

Comment: @Miro You need access to `MyBase` sources if you would like to add a "copy" constructor. If you do not have this access, you could make a shared static method that copies `MyBase` properties from one instance to another, to avoid duplicating the same code across multiple derived classes.

Comment: @Miro You should also seriously consider Jon's suggestion about composition instead of inheritance, there is a change that it might be appropriate in your case.

Answer (score 9):

You can't, basically. You could use reflection to copy the values in an automated way, but it would still be copying them one-by-one, and wouldn't give you as much control over *how* they were copied (e.g. whether you needed to make a deep copy).

As dasblinkenlight states, it may be more appropriate to make each class responsible for copying its own properties, unless that's not something that is always appropriate.

Note that you might want to check whether `prototype` is *itself* an instance of `MySecond`, and copy the properties from that if so.

Also note that if you use composition instead of inheritance, and try to make classes immutable, a lot of the time this kind of thing becomes unnecessary or trivial. It's not always appropriate, but I see quite a lot of overuse of inheritance.

Comment: +1 The note on using composition instead of inheritance is very useful.